# Adding tool from Python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, arcmap, python-2.7

I am trying to add Python script as a tool in ArcMap 10.6. I have the result or outcop3 saved in the folder Outputs. I added a output folder in the parameter and made the direction as output but i am unable to find this Outputs folder when i click on the parent folder. All i can see is the main folder called "Test". Why is it so? I am adding the script i used here.

```
import arcpy
import os
import sys
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Raster1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
......
Outputs = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
env.workspace = r"C:\Test"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "MINOF"
Raster1 = Raster("Raster_one")
.....
outcop3 = Con(Raster4 == 1,2)

outcop3.save(r"C:/Test/Outputs/outcop3") 
´´´
```

Comment: Is your C:\ drive on a shared network computer, such as one accessed via Citrix or RDP?  If so, I've found that IT departments appear to sometimes hide the contents of certain drives, like the C:\ drive, to discourage people from poking around and creating folders like "Test" at the root of the C:\ drive.  If you have another drive you can use elsewhere, it may be worth changing your workspace and output paths to somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks it worked when i changed from C drive. But i am still getting an error like this with the script."ERROR 000875: Output raster: H:\Test\Output\outcon0805's workspace is an invalid output workspace"

Comment: Does your Output folder already exist?

Comment: Yes i have already created the output folder and now i can find it in the parent folder. But the new problem is i want the output name to be decided by the user who runs the tool. How can this be done?

Comment: You would use the arcpy.GetParameterAsText() function.  See https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/accessing-parameters-in-a-script-tool.htm

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved now :)